# GCP: Trying to hit an Internal load balancer (internal IP) from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, load-balancing

We have 3-4 services which we deploy via Instance Groups on GCP. We use an internal HTTP load balancer to allow access to these services within the network.

Now we also have some independent Cloud Functions running in the same project. We are looking to hit the internal load balancer IP from these cloud functions. We are able to hit directly the IPs of VMs from cloud function by setting up a serverless VPC as described in this [blog](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access?authuser=5&_ga=2.71140054.-738149944.1648799042). However calls to load balancer are not happening. Are we missing some other firewall rules to be configured? Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Solution**:

The Cloud Function, Serverless VPC and internal Load Balancer have to be in the same region. By placing all of them in same region we were able to solve the issue.

Comment: We cannot say if you're missing any firewall rules if you do not show your actual rules. Please add more details to your question to avoid the community to be guessing what could be the issue

Comment: Edit your question with details on the VPC connector. You will need a firewall rule allowing traffic from the connector's custom IP range.

Comment: Do you have logs on your VPC or your LB? Can you confirm that you use an internal HTTPS load balancer (not a TCP/UDP LB)? Are you in the same region or in different regions?*

Comment: Please share your firewall rules and details on your VPC connector. By the way, what documentation are you following?

Comment: I’m glad to hear that problem has been resolved. 

Could you please post an answer with an explanation? As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it is a very good practice and it will be helpful in the future for other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, the Cloud Function, Serverless VPC, and internal Load Balancer [have to be in the same region](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Region%20field%2C%20select%20a%20region%20for%20your%20connector.%20This%20must%20match%20the%20region%20of%20your%20serverless%20service.). By placing all of them in the same region, you could solve the issue.